# Medical protein modeling software for finding cures to medical diseases (via, chemical and mathematical, modeling)

Tags: android, educational, modeling, accessibility, android-app

I wonder whether there is any software on Android that lets you:

1. Model proteins or other molecules, by entering their chemical composition or entering Atome from periodic tables
2. Storing the proteins in named protein lists with chemical formulas
3. modeling protein folds
4. Modeling contact with agents which may cause this or that other protein fold
5. Modeling molecule infections or reactions, in, seriate, reaction sheets (that can also be chained, in graphs, to model chain reactions).

This software, would be very useful in medical applications, for finding cures to medical conditions and diseases.

Where can I find such software?

Thanks.